# MATCH() one of multiple values in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, financial

I have 100+ sheets of financial data, and i am creating a master sheet, with all the companies data on one comprehensive sheet. I have almost everything, but the problem is companies sometimes list Revenue Per share as many different things (could be Total Sales per share, Total Sales per ADR, Net Operating Revenues per share, etc).

The thing is, since none of these are listed together, each sheet will always have only one of those from the list.

Is there a way to use the MATCH function with a list of values, and if one of them exists in the specified Array, give me that row number?

For example:

lets say sheet1 has the value "Net Operating Revenues per share", and i want to use the match function without looking and having to specify. Instead, i just want to list some values, and if MATCH finds ONE of them, give me that row?

Comment: Will those columns ("Total Sales per share", "total sales per ADR", etc.) be the only columns with "Per" in them? If so, you can have the formula look for any column with "per" instead of the whole string.

Comment: firstly, you can use an array as the input to the lookup value in Match (make sure to catch errors). So that is one option (e.g. in a formula like `{=MIN(IFERROR(Match({1,2,3},A1:A10,0),""))}`). Secondly, you can also use wildcards so you could try something like `=Match("Total Sales per*",A1:A10,0)`. The two techniques can be combined: `{=MIN(IFERROR(Match("Total Sales per*","Net Operating Revenues per*"},A1:A10,0),""))}`. And of course if you want to use VBA, you can use the Like operator (or the worksheet function Match) to achieve a similar result.

Comment: To follow on from my above comment: A much better and more rigourous approach is to compile a list of all the metrics the companies use and then for you to assign (called mapping) these to your desired final metric/category. Your lookups then compare the company's phrase against your mapping. This way, you are 100% sure of what is happening.

Comment: @user3578951 no, unfortunately they're many cells with "per share"

Comment: @Cor_Blimey mhmm your first method seems interesting, addressnig your second comment, would that be achieved using the Name Manager?

Comment: @JackRob no, I mean, for example, that some companies call the top-line Sales and other Revenue. They also might call their top line costs Cost of Goods Sold or they might call it Cost of Sales. Etc etc throughout the P&L.You should compile (through VBA or otherwise) a list of all the unique terms used in one column. You then, in the next, decide that you want to map Cost of Goods Sold and Cost of Sales to the same line in your summary (e.g. COGS). Your lookup then compares the text used in the company P&L to your list, and so works out what it is meant to be for your summary.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to simply chain multiple `MATCH` statements together with the different strings you would like to test. Return the value of the first one that doesn't return an error (`#N/A`).

For example:

```
=IFERROR(MATCH("Total Sales Per Share", FinancialData!A1:A100,0),
         MATCH("Total Sales Per ADR", FinancialData!A1:A100,0))
```

If you are willing to use arrays, the following code will also work, but will still be fairly verbose. Note that the worksheet `LookupTerms` will contain an array of lookup terms, and `FinancialData` will contain the array in which you are searching for the terms:

```
{=MIN(IFERROR(Match(LookupTerms!A1:A10, FinancialData!A1:A100, 0), ""))}
```

Another option would be to employ VBA in your answer. The following code will allow you to specify a range of lookup terms and a lookup array. It will look through the lookup terms for the first term that is found in the lookup array, and return the index of that match.

```
Function MatchMultiple(lookup_terms As Range, lookup_array As Range) As Double
    Dim result As Variant
    Dim lookup_term As Range

    For Each lookup_term In lookup_terms.Cells
        If Not IsEmpty(lookup_term.Value) Then
            result = WorksheetFunction.Match(lookup_term, lookup_array, 0)

            If Not IsError(result) Then
                MatchMultiple = result
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
    Next

    MatchMultiple = CVErr(xlErrNA)
End Function
```

Add this function to a module, and then call it as follows:

```
=MatchMultiple(LookupTerms!A1:A10, FinancialData!A1:A100)
```

Comment: ahh that is a good idea. i'll give that a shot, and see if that works and report back

Comment: +1 nice function. If N(lookup array) * N(lookup terms) is large, it would be more efficient (change to almost O(N) performance) to construct a dictionary of one or the other (probably the lookup array) and perform hash lookups (simply build a collection: `On Error Resume Next: For each item in lookup_array: lookupCollection.Add item, item.value: Next` then simply check each lookup term to see if it exists in the collection: `For each item in lookup_term: Set foundRng = lookupCollection(item.Value): If err.Number = 0 then MsgBox("Found it!"): next`.

Comment: using this VBA, where would i define these lookup_terms, and will i be able to incorporate this into an hlookup function? the sheets im pulling from have multiple years, so i need the index of "Total sales per share" within my hlookup to return the value for that specific year.

Comment: @JackRob `lookup_terms` is simply a reference to a range on a sheet, like a list of your terms you want to be considered for Revenue per share. For example you could use it like: `=MatchMultiple(A1:A10, CompanyX!A1:A100)` where A1:A10 is a list of all the things you have decided are ok for that particular metric. You don't have to use it in VBA if you don't want to. You can use it in a formula Excel. If you want to use it from VBA without reference to an existing list of cells then you will need to adapt it to take an array (or enumerable) as argument to `lookup_term` instead of `Range`.

Comment: thanks, thats more clear. if i implemented this VBA, where would the index value be spit out? would i be able to populate a column with it? or could i put it in a formula?

Comment: @JackRob if you implemented it in VBA the function would return the position within `lookup_array` that a match was found. So you use that to get whatever year or whatever your columns represent. E.g. combine it with Index to pull out the relevant value from the sheet. Say your values were in columns B:D for years FY14, FY13, FY12 respetively then then you could stick an index function in your main sheet as `=Index(CompanyX!B$1:B$100, MatchMultiple(lookupTerms!$A$1:$A$5,CompanyX!$A$1:$A$100))` and drag across, and it would pull in the relevant data for that company for each fiscal year

Comment: @Cor_Blimey hey, i feel stupid, i understand now, its a function. my only problem is when i enter in the formula to call that function, MatchMultiple will come up, then when i put in the parameters and press enter, i'm getting "The name you entered is not valid..... reasons can include......"

Comment: @Cor_Blimey I got it to work on a blank new workbook, so something with my existing macros must mess with this? either way, when i get it to work, it seems that it will only work with the top value of the selected "lookupTerms" array. so if i have A1:A4 being: Chocolate, Vanilla, Strawberry, Cherry, matchmultiple only is returning me anything if Chocolate is in the second array

Comment: @JackRob sorry for the delay. Which book is the function in? If it is not in the same book as the worksheet you are entering the formula in then you need to qualify it with the workbook name. The easiest way to find the right thing to use is to use the Formula Wizard (click a blank cell, click the fX button next to the formula bar, then in the dropdown click on user-defined and find the function in the list). If you have the right function and it still isn't working can you please post in your comment the formula you are passing in as an example?